# Conflict between Options of Packages

Tags: incompatibility, package-options, option-clash

I have these following packages defined in my preamble and once the file is ran, it creates an error of the following saying there is a clash within the package options. Packages are below:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
 .......    
\end{document}
```

[image: Error Log]

Is there a way to prevent and what is the actual root of the problem to persist?

Comment: `tikz` is the package which already loads `xcolor`

Comment: `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}` as I alread wrote in my answer

Comment: Okay, right. When putting commands like that before `\documentclass{...}`, is that like in a sense making a global variable?

Comment: no, as said it only prevents an option clash

Comment: @Herbet: I did not mean that command in particular. I meant in general, when putting commands before `\documentclass` in a teX file.

Comment: yes, they are global because it is the highest level

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{...}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

However, it looks like that `xcolor` is already loaded by your documentclass or another package

Comment: @Herbet: Hmm, interesting if it could be the documentclass. The document looks like this: `\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}`.

Comment: @night owl: that class doesn't load a color package, so it is antother package which does it. However, you could use the above code to prevent option mismatch, it is always save.

Comment: @Herbet: Okay that is a good idea. You meant to say it is always "safe" right, besides using the word "save"? `:)`

Comment: @night owl:  uuh, always the same problem: my fingers and my brain are not synchronized ;-)

Comment: @Herbet: Hahahaha, no worries, I think 'almost' all of us computer gals/guys have this problem when we think on our toes but body mechanics is just too slow to tag along.

Answer (score 11):

Well, since Herbert provide a general solution for option clash, here is another solution:

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Just put `xcolor` package *before* `tikz` package.

Explanation:

In LaTeX, you cannot load a package through `\usepackage` twice or more. If a package has been loaded, another `\usepackage` *without* any options will be safely ignored, but a `\usepackage` *with* some options will produce an option clash.

`tikz` package loads `xcolor` internally without any options. If you want to use `xcolor` with additional options, you can use it before `tikz`.

---

You can even use this way to prevent the option clash:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Options for `\documentclass` are global. These options will be passed to any later packages if possible. It is especially useful if you want to pass an option to a package that loaded by the document class. However, it isn't as precise as `\PassOptionsToPackage`.

Comment: @ Leo: +1...Thanks alot. This was some very enlightening info to know and explanation was on point. Its good to learn something without any confusion.

Comment: that makes sense if you are really sure, that _all_ packages should get this option. This is not in all cases a good choice

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
abcdefgh
\end{document}
```

does not produce any warnings or errors on a current TeXlive 2011 installation.

If you are using additional packages (`hyperref` is one that this problem is seen with, for example) here may well be ways round the problem: for example, try using the xcolor `svgnames` option if that color range is appropriate, use explicit `\definecolor` commands or try various diagnostic procedures.

Providing more information, including a complete but minimal size working example of the problem would help provide better responses.

Comment: @ mas: Hmm, wonder if that could be it. I currently am running of of MikTeX...