# getting an option clash with Babel, [english,greek]

Tags: babel

I am getting an option clash for babel using: `\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}`.  Here is the output:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package babel.
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?  I've tried Googling and have seen many others use these options together, but I cannot get it to work.  Here is my full latex heading:

```
\documentclass[article,11pt]{Latex/Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF}
\raggedbottom
\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\makeatletter
\def\NAT@def@citea{\def\@citea{\NAT@separator}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: It's because the class you're using (I googled for it and found it [here](http://web.mit.edu/carrien/Public/latex/phd/PhDtemplateLATEX/Latex/Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF.cls)) already calls `babel` with the `english` option. The solution is to pass the `greek` option when loading the class file (`\documentclass[greek,<...>]{<class>}`. You could also call it with a `\PassOptionsToPackage{greek,english}{babel}` *before* `\documentclass` (as shown in the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25664))

Comment: @henrique, why don't you make this comment an answer?

Comment: unrelated to the problem but the argument to `\documentclass` is supposed to be the `name` of a class not a file path `\documentclass[article,11pt]{Latex/Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF}` should be `\documentclass[article,11pt]{PhDthesisPSnPDF}` after ensurimg that `latex/classes` is in your TeX input path.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle here's how the class file names it: `\ProvidesClass{Latex/Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF}[2007/09/06 v2 PhD thesis class]`

Comment: @nickie, I did so, but I think it's a possible duplicate of [Conflict between Options of Packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25664/conflict-between-options-of-packages)

Comment: @henrique uggg:(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because the class you're using (available [here](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20120531231838/http://web.mit.edu/carrien/Public/latex/phd/PhDtemplateLATEX/Latex/Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF.cls)) already calls `babel` with the `english` option. The solution is to pass the `greek` option when loading the class file with

```
\documentclass[greek,<...>]{<class>}
```

You could also call it with a `\PassOptionsToPackage{greek,english}{babel}` *before* loading the package, therefore *before* `\documentclass`, since the class is loading it.

See:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25664;
- [Heiko Oberdiek's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183909) to [Passing options to loaded package not working with Beamer class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/183907/5872;)
- ["Option Clash for Package" at the TeX FAQ](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-optionclash)

Comment: In my opinion classes should never load `babel` or `inputenc`: it just makes life more difficult for users. It's surely simpler telling them to load `babel` with the desired language options.

Comment: Note that if you're using `\PassOptionsToPackage`, this should be called _before_ the `\usepackage` command. This may seem trivial, but isn't always for a newbie.

Comment: @CamilStaps Good point. I added some more links to (I hope) help clarify this